# $_SERVER['document_root'] subdomains

Tags: php, include, document-root

On a php file I have

```
include_once($_SERVER['document_root'] .'/path/to/file.php');
```

When I'm viewing the file which has the code in for example test.php, if I have this URL formatting it works fine:

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/test.php
```

But if it's a subdomain, like this:

```
http://path.example.com/to/test.php
```

I get an error saying the path to `file.php` that is `included` into the file does not exist.

I've tried putting in a full url `include_once('http://www.example.com/path/to/file.php');`.

How can I get this to work under subdomains?

Comment: The document root is a file path. Include as `/path/on/filesystem/file.php` rather than as a URL.

Comment: but the subdomain makes it not work.

Comment: The subdomain makes it not work on `http://sub.domain.com/path/to/file.php`. If you use the file system path it's the same no matter what the URL is.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked, if you write this out as an answer, I'll award you the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include one php file from other domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875935/how-to-include-one-php-file-from-other-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the file-systempath. You cannot include from other URL.

Comment: Not strictly true - you can `include()` from a URL if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in php.ini and the URL is serving a raw unprocessed PHP file http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php